# C# - How do I create an exception if the User enters a text when expecting a number?

Tags: c#

Here is the code I had written for a Calculator without any tutorial, and I want to keep it that way, so I want to imagine and create my own code since i'm just a beginner.

```
Console.Title = "My Epic Calculator !";

            var numOne = "";
            var numTwo = "";
            var term = "";
            var answer = 0;
            
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello there, welcome to my calculator !\nIt can calculate everything. Come on, try it !");

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number below.");
                        numOne = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (numOne == "")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valud number");
                        }

                        int firstTerm = int.Parse(numOne);

                    Console.WriteLine("Now enter your second number.");
                        numTwo = Console.ReadLine();
                        int secondTerm = int.Parse(numTwo);

                    Console.WriteLine("Choose your mathematical option: x, /, + and -");
                        term = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (term == "x")
                        {
                            answer = firstTerm * secondTerm;
                        }

                            else if (term == "/")
                            {
                                answer = firstTerm / secondTerm;
                            }

                            else if (term == "+")
                            {
                                answer = firstTerm + secondTerm;
                            }

                            else if (term == "-")
                            {
                                answer = firstTerm - secondTerm;
                            }

                        
                    Console.WriteLine($"And your answer is {answer}, see it's pretty cool huh!");
                    
                    Console.ReadKey();
```

As you can see, it lacks an exception if the user enters in text where you expect a number to be written in (numOne / numTwo for example). And unfortunately I don't know how to resolve this, can anyone help? Thank you.

I would also appreciate a few tips to optimise my code as I know it is very messy with my tons of If's.

Comment: Are you just looking for `int.TryParse()`?  It's not really clear to me what specifically you're asking, or what exactly you mean by "it lacks an exception".

Comment: `int.Parse()` will throw an exception, so you don't have to. However, a more user friendly option might be to loop until they enter a number.

Comment: Once you get the code working as you want it to, you can post it at [codereview.se] for feedback.

Comment: Throwing an exception is not a good idea. Your code should be able to handle this expected “mistake” from the user and continue to work despite this invalid user input. Users make mistakes, just tell the user the number is not valid and try again.

Comment: I suggest you create a method, that takes a string prompt and returns an `int` or whatever numeric type you want. In the method, make an infinite loop that ask the user for the number and then checks what the users enters and keep asking the user for the number until they actually type a valid number. You then could use this same method for both the first and second number. I suggest you look at the `TryParse` method of numeric type you use to help you validate the user’s input.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp what I meant is that I want to give the user an error message if they entered text instead of numbers and make it ask the needed information again.

Comment: @AARAEN: Then you'd use `int.TryParse()` to parse the input, checking if that parsing fails.  If it fails, show an error to the user.  There's no need to involve exceptions here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int numOneIntValue= 0;
> if (!int.TryParse(numOne, out numOneIntValue))
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("numOne  is not a number!");
> }
> int numTwoIntValue= 0 ;
> if (!int.TryParse(numTwo , out numTwoIntValue))
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("numTwo is not a number!");
> }
> ```